# How to randomly rotate Wordpress short-code output in sidebar?

Tags: wordpress

I've enabled Wordpress shortcode output to work in the sidebar and am using the '[enhanced text widget](http://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-text-widget/)' (which allows PHP, short codes, javascript etc) to output Polldaddy polls using the shortcode given by polldaddy such as: [polldaddy poll="xxxxxxx"], which works fine together with Polldaddy's own [WP plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/polldaddy/).

I'd like to either randomly show or even better cycle through more than one poll so that the site visitor sees a different poll at each page refresh.

I get short-codes are excuted server side so would most likely need a php script.

I've found lots of ad banner rotators and quote rotators on the internet but could not make anything work.

I'd be grateful if someone would share a solution.

Thanks

T.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own "meta" Shortcode to create random Poll Shortcodes, like:

```
add_shortcode( 'randompoll', 'poll_so_17134362');

function poll_so_17134362( $atts ) 
{
    $random_poll = your_method_to_get_random_polls();
    $return = do_shortcode( '[polldaddy poll="' . $random_poll . '"]' );
    return $return;
}
```